# Jquery - binding click event to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

All,

I am really stuck/ confused at this point.

I have an array with 6 items in it. Each item in the array is dynamically filled with elements using jquery '.html' method. However, I cannot seem to be able to attach/ bind an event to this dynamically created variable.

As soon as the browser gets to the problem line (see the area labeled 'PROBLEM AREA'), I get a 'undefined' error, which is really confusing as all the previous code on the very same variable works just fine.

```
var eCreditSystem = document.getElementById("creditSystem");
var i = 0;
var eCreditT = new Array(6);                    // 6 members created which will be recycled

function createCreditTransaction ()                 // func called when a transaction occurs, at the mo, attached to onclick()
{
    if (i < 6)
    {
        eCreditT[i] = undefined;                    // to delete the existing data in the index of array
        addElements (i);
    } else
    if (i > 5 || eCreditT[i] != undefined)
    {
         ...
    }
}

function addElements (arrayIndex)                   // func called from within the 'createCreditTransaction()' func
{
    eCreditT[i] = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass("cCreditTransaction").appendTo(eCreditSystem);
    $(eCreditT[i]).attr ('id', ('trans' + i));
    $(eCreditT[i]).html ('<div class="cCreditContainer"><span class="cCreditsNo">-50</span>&nbsp;<img class="cCurrency" src="" alt="" /></div><span class="cCloseMsg">Click box to close.</span><div class="dots"></div><div class="dots"></div><div class="dots"></div>');
    creditTransactionSlideOut (eCreditT[i], 666);                   // calling slideOut animation
    console.log(eCreditT[i]);     // this confirms that the variable is not undefined

/* ***** THE PROBLEM AREA ***** */
    $(eCreditT[i]).on ('click', function ()                 // if user clicks on the transaction box
    {
        creditTransactionSlideBackIn (eCreditT[i], 150);                    // slide back in animation
    });
    return i++;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering, could this have something to do with where the js file is loaded in the HTML doc from? 

I have the js file placed at the bottom of the body tag in HTML.

Comment: Second theory is that is it possible that by the time it gets to 'binding' the event to the variable, the browser has already read & implemented the 'return i++', which would mean that at that moment, the 'eCreditT[i]' has a different value for 'i' than previously?

Comment: Its worked! But I have no real idea of why it worked.

When I commented the 'return i++' & ran the code, it worked. Now my problem is how do I implement the 'return i++' at the end of the function?

Comment: Try to add click event out of addElements() function and try once.

Comment: @Kiran, thankyou, that DID work. I actually had tried this before as well but I must have done something wrong then as its clearly working now. A million thanks.

Comment: @Kiran, please post as separate answer so I can choose it as the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add click event out of addElements() function and try once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(eCreditT[i]).bind('click', function() {
   creditTransactionSlideBackIn(eCreditT[i], 150);
});
```

**Edit:** use `++i` instead of `i++` like this:

```
return ++i;
/*
or
i += 1;
return i;
*/
```

`retrurn ++i` performs the increment first then return `i` after the increment.
While `return i++` return `i` then icrement it.

Comment: Tried it already, doesn't work. eCreditT[i] is supposedly undefined.

Comment: thanks & its supposedly resolved, however a new issue has arisen. Please have a look at the last comment to the original post.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I didn't know the difference between ++i & i++. Did a search & apparently ++i returns the updates i while i++ doesn't, surely thats not the case in js as my functions are working correctly... ?

Answer (score 1):

Nonsense create an element using JavaScript and then use jQuery function to transform it into a jQuery object. You can let jQuery create the element directly for you.

```
eCreditT[i] = $('<div>').addClass("cCreditTransaction").appendTo(eCreditSystem);
```

Also, since eCretitT[i] is already a jQuery element, no need to call the jQuery function again.

```
eCreditT[i].on('click', function () {
    creditTransactionSlideBackIn(eCreditT[i], 150);
});
```

If you already tried `on`, `bind`, `live` and `click` methods, then maybe the called function is your problem. Try to put a `console.log()` or an `alert()` inside the function to make sure the click event is actually happening. If it happens then the function `creditTransactionSlideBackIn()` is your problem.

**EDIT**

The problem is when the event takes place, `i` is not the original variable anymore.

```
function addElements (arrayIndex)
{
    eCreditT[i] = $('<div>').addClass("cCreditTransaction").appendTo(eCreditSystem);
    eCreditT[i].attr ('id', ('trans' + i));

    eCreditT[i].data ('id', i);    // Store the id value to a data attribute
```

Then when you call the function you can refer to the data attribute instead of the `i` variable:

```
/* ***** THE PROBLEM AREA ***** */
    eCreditT[i].on ('click', function ()                 // if user clicks on the transaction box
    {
        creditTransactionSlideBackIn ($(this).data('id'), 150);                    // slide back in animation
    });
    return i++;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the top tip. Implemented. Regarding the actual problem, I have it resolved... partly. It appears that the 'return i++' is at fault. Please see my last comment to my original post.

Comment: Edited with a proposed solution to store and retrieve the right id value at the right moment.

Comment: thank you @Jose Faeti. Im looking into the data method for jquery.

Answer (score 1):

try to bind parent div and then use `if($e.target).is('some')){}`, it will act as .live, like this:

```
$(eCreditSystem).bind('click', function (e){
    if($(e.target).is('.cCreditTransaction')) {
        creditTransactionSlideBackIn ($(e.target), 150);              
    }
});
```

of course you'll need in a minute larger `if` for checking if clicked dom el is a child of `.cCreditTransaction`, like this:

```
if($(e.target).parents().is('.cCreditTransaction')){}
```

Comment: Im a bit confused, would you please shed some more light on why/how binding parent div would help. Am reading up on '.live' & '.is' in the meantime :)

Comment: edit ^^ ;)
and you should put this lines outside addElements func, explanation is this: while you add element to container and click on it, event will occur, only one condition is required, clicked object must be with class 'cCreditTransaction'. to bind function it doesn't matter what is inside of a container, function check for required element everytime something is clicked inside of a container ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(eCreditT[i]).live('click', function() {
   creditTransactionSlideBackIn(eCreditT[i], 150);
});
```

Comment: Does not work. Now Javascript console is reporting:
uncaught exception: syntax error, unrecognized expression: )